# How to send response from PHP to Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This JavaScript code uses POST method to send data from form to PHP where PHP checks in database if data is true. But I don't know how to send response from PHP back to JS that fetching was successful. Can someone explain?

**JS:**

```js
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {

  var dataString = 'username=' + document.getElementById('username').value + '&password=' + document.getElementById('password').value + '&rememberMe=' + document.getElementById('rememberMe').value;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
      //check if what response is   
    } 
  });
```

**ajaxsubmit.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

//connect

$username =$_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='$username' OR username ='$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){     
    //response error
} else{
     //response success
}

?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You have to `echo` something in your PHP to get information returned to AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you echo out in the php will be sent back to the ajax.

```
if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo 0;
}
 else{
     echo 1;
}
```

---

```
success: function(response){
    //check if what response is
    console.log( response );
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` will not give you a popup.

Answer (score 1):

You have to echo something in your PHP to get something returned:

```
if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //response error
    echo 'there is a problem';
} else {    
     //response success
     echo 'yippee!';
}
```

Then you can log the return as follows:

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {

    var dataString = 'username=' + document.getElementById('username').value + '&password=' + document.getElementById('password').value + '&rememberMe=' + document.getElementById('rememberMe').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){ // 'data' is the variable holding the return from PHP's echo
        //check if what response is   
           console.log(data);
     } 
});
```

[Make sure to watch the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools. Make sure you included the jQuery library in the project. The console will reveal errors. AJAX requires a web server.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

**WARNING** [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

**DANGER** **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit method with response parameters. like:

**ajaxsubmit.php**

```
if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){     
    exit('error');  //exit with response 'error'
} else{
     exit('success'); //exit with response 'success'
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {

  var dataString = 'username=' + document.getElementById('username').value + '&password=' + document.getElementById('password').value + '&rememberMe=' + document.getElementById('rememberMe').value;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
      //check if what response is   
      console.log(response);
    } 
  });
```